# Questions about the correct use of matplotlib rcParams

Tags: excel, python-2.7, matplotlib, xelatex

I'm writing a report for my physic experiment. 
For this I use PyLab64bit, XeLaTex, Excel.
I write the measurements in an excel sheet and then use import -xlrd to get the data for the .py script with which I do the plots and calculations. The plots are saved as .pdf and included in the .tex file later.

Now most of the steps above works fine, I was happy with my first report. 
However for the second report I need some enhancements, mostly about text in color and the font matching.

If I look at the second example given here (http://matplotlib.org/users/usetex.html)

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['text.usetex']=True
mpl.rcParams['text.latex.unicode']=True
from numpy import arange, cos, pi
from matplotlib.pyplot import (figure, axes, plot, xlabel, ylabel, title,
 grid, savefig, show)

figure(1, figsize=(6,4))
ax = axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.7])
t = arange(0.0, 1.0+0.01, 0.01)
s = cos(2*2*pi*t)+2
plot(t, s)

xlabel(r'\textbf{time (s)}')
ylabel(r'\textit{Velocity (\u00B0/sec)}', fontsize=16)
title(r"\TeX\ is Number $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{-e^{i\pi}}{2^n}$!",
  fontsize=16, color='r')
grid(True)
show()
```

I want to adjust this example to match my preference. For this purpose I have take a look at this site (http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html) which gives me information about the rcParams settings.
However I am confused and need your help to understand this better. Ideally I want that the plots are done with the fonts chosen for the .tex file. This is in my case XITS regular and XITS Math for inline formulae.

I have the following questions:

• If I want to use another font not listed for rcParams, what do I need to do?

• If I want the most similar input style as in latex for the labels, using Δ∀∀ΦΛ×Θ etc. will work without adjustment?

• If I adjust the rcParams can I just do this in each own .py file or do I need to specify a complete rcParams config file on its own?

• To get the best match from the preview to the actual figure included in latex which tweaks exists?

• It seems that there exist many ways of including latex-style text in matplotlib. Has one a good overview over the differences?

**Thank you in advance!** 
*I really like the functionality given in matplotlib but as a beginner it is hard for me to understand this in further depth. I mean if I simply use the basic commands given it is OK for the simple plots, but this will not lead to a proper solution if the next plot is more complicated. 
F.g. two y-axes with different colors, ticks spacing, offset axis, labeling position, lin-log-scale. At least from my point of view I really want to understand the underlying principle which seems more complicated first but then I can with much less effort adjust those to fit a completely new output style.*